# Images not loading after hosting app on godaddy

Tags: angular, deployment

Hello I am trying to deploy a static angular website on godaddy server. I did

```
ng build --prod
```

which created a `dist` folder and I copy pasted the files inside to the godaddy plesk. Everything got loaded except `assests` folder and the website is working fine but all the images have not loaded.

Please help on how to load the assests folder

Comment: how have you added the image src to the angular code , it si relative path or static ?

Comment: I have added it like (../assets/images/foldername/filename.jpg)

Comment: Write his nick name as he wont be notified - @Rahul Singh

Comment: Change your image path to this: `(/assets/images/foldername/filename.jpg)` ... without `..` at start.